# Задача на сумму матриц

Tags: алгоритм, математика, матрицы, сложность

Допустим у меня есть некая матрица A размера q×q. Мне нужно найти сумму A + A<sup>2</sup> + ... + A<sup>n</sup>, при этом сложность вычисления этой суммы должна быть O(q<sup>3</sup>log(n)). Как это сделать?

Comment: А для матриц выполняется свойство суммы геометрической прогрессии?

Answer (score 10):

Сначала немного матричной математики...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Откуда совсем просто получается (*I* - единичная матрица)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

так что

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну, а дальше использовать [быстрое возведение в степень](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D1%8B_%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C), которое требует *log(n)* умножений. Каждое умножение - не будем умничать и звать на помощь Штрассена :) - выполняется за *q<sup>3</sup>*. Вычитание - за *q<sup>2</sup>*, обратная матрица - *q<sup>3</sup>*. Таким образом, в результате получается требуемая сложность *O(q<sup>3</sup>log(n))*.

Comment: А что если, (A - I) - не обратима? Как тогда нам вычислить по формуле?

Comment: Тогда включаете голову и думаете сами :)